# Python dictionary is splitting string keys by character

Tags: python

I am new to Python and I have been having some issues with dictionaries.

My aim is to get a dictionary as below:

done_dict = {orthogroup1: 1, orthogroup2: 1, orthogroup3: 1}

So far I have the following:

```
for orthogroup_name in done_match:
    split_name =  orthogroup_name.split('.')
    split_name = split_name[0]
    done_dict = dict.fromkeys(split_name)
    done_dict = dict.fromkeys
    print(done_dict)
```

With this I get something like this:

```
{'g': None, 'h': None, 'o': None, '1': None, 'p': None, 'r': None, 'u': None, 't': None, '6': None, '8': None}
```

Can somebody help explain how do I turn None into 1 and how I get python to not split every character into a new key?

Thank you so very much!

Comment: What is `done_match`?  If it is a list of orthogroup names, `dict.fromkeys(done_match, 1)` is probably sufficient.

Comment: done_match is an array of files with the extension '.done' (e.g. 'orthogroup912.faa.aligned.done'). I only want the orthogroup_number (i.e. no the '.faa.aligned.done' bit), hence the splitting. thank you!

Comment: the problem is here: `dict.fromkeys(split_name)` split_name is a string and fromkeys turns it into a list of characters to use as keys

Answer (score 4):

`fromkeys` expects an iterable of keys that is uses to build the dictionary.  You're providing it a single key at a time, which it is interpreting as an iterable of characters.

You can set up a generator expression to process the file names into the keys, and then give that generator to `fromkeys`:

```
processed_names = (name.split('.')[0] for name in done_match)
d = dict.from_keys(processed_names, 1)
```